# How do I verify a downloaded Catalina installer, certificate untrusted

Tags: catalina, verify

I have downloaded a Catalina installer from App Store / full-fetch terminal method.

When I run `pkgutil` at the installer located in the Applications folder it says certificate untrusted. This is what I get in Terminal:

```
Package "Install macOS Catalina":
   Status: signed by untrusted certificate
   Certificate Chain:
    1. Software Signing
       SHA256 Fingerprint:
           2A A4 B9 97 3B 7B A0 7A DD 44 7E E4 DA 8B 53 37 C3 EE 2C 3A 99 19 
           11 E8 0E 72 82 E8 A7 51 FC 32
       ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    2. Apple Code Signing Certification Authority
       Expires: 2026-10-24 17:39:41 +0000
       SHA256 Fingerprint:
           5B DA B1 28 8F C1 68 92 FE F5 0C 65 8D B5 4F 1E 2E 19 CF 8F 71 CC 
           55 F7 7D E2 B9 5E 05 1E 25 62
       ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    3. Apple Root CA
       Expires: 2035-02-09 21:40:36 +0000
       SHA256 Fingerprint:
           B0 B1 73 0E CB C7 FF 45 05 14 2C 49 F1 29 5E 6E DA 6B CA ED 7E 2C 
           68 C5 BE 91 B5 A1 10 01 F0 24
```

Comment: when I do the exact method with a Monterey downloaded installer it passes and says signed by Apple. 

are the Catalina installers not signed anymore ?

Comment: Please *edit* your question to add details, don't just add comments.